# insert a jquery string into a php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```
$sub_array[] =array('<a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Elimina</a>'); 
$data[] = $sub_array;
```

and would like to add:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
```

to it. I tried:

```
$sub_array[] =array('<a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">Elimina</a>'); 
$data[] = $sub_array;
```

but am receiving an error.

Comment: Look at your quotes. You need to escape the JS encapsulation quotes so they don't close the PHP ones. A good editor would tell you this, PHP also would tell you this if error reporting used.

Comment: Use some IDE which highlights code errors, also when you passed the code here and it was colored it's easy to see that you are using quotes in wrong way. Please remove basic  errors and mistakes in your question before/instead of posting!

Answer (score 1):

Mixing three different languages on a single line of code is just asking for quoting problems.  At the very least, any time you have quoted strings inside of quoted strings then you need to *escape* those quotes:

```
'"    onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete?\');">Elimina</a>'
```

Otherwise the syntax parser isn't going to know what you want to be a string literal vs. what you want to be part of the language syntax.

As a longer-term approach, I'd recommend that you start separating your JavaScript from your HTML.  (You can further clean up things by separating your HTML from your PHP, likely using a PHP framework or templating engine of some kind, though I'm less familiar with the PHP parts of things.)

Using something like [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in a separate JavaScript file referenced from your page would be a clean approach.  Basically all your PHP would be doing is rendering the HTML, and then in a separate `.js` file referenced by a `<script>` element in that HTML you would add the event handlers to your target elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quoting issue as mentioned above. It would appear that you're not using IDE software to write your code, or at least one without syntax highlighting. I would look into that because it will make things like this super easy to debug.

The following should however work! :)

```
$sub_array[] = array("<a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');\">Elimina</a>"); 
$data[] = $sub_array;
```